# Check if two views have the same column values

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-view

I try to explain my problem in the simplest way.

I have a table, let's call it **Table_A**, structured like this:

`ID | Name | Code | Status | Counter_A | Counter_B | Counter_C`

This Table_A is filled with data once a day.

A second table, named **Table_B**, structurally identical to the previous one, takes the data in real-time (it is refreshed over and over again a day).

I have to find a way to highlight daily if and which counter (Counter_A, Counter_B, Counter_C) is different between Table_A and Table_B.

A numerical example:

**Table_A**

| ID | Name | Code | Status | Counter_A | Counter_B | Counter_C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | aaa | 971283 | online | 0 | 3 | 0 |
| 02 | bbb | 287301 | online | 4 | 2 | 2 |
| 03 | ccc | 718923 | online | 5 | 5 | 5 |
| 04 | ddd | 789021 | online | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 05 | eee | 890123 | online | 1 | 1 | 4 |

**Table_B**

| ID | Name | Code | Status | Counter_A | Counter_B | Counter_C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | aaa | 971283 | online | 0 | 3 | **1** |
| 02 | bbb | 287301 | online | **0** | 2 | 2 |
| 03 | ccc | 718923 | online | 5 | 5 | 5 |
| 04 | ddd | 789021 | online | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 05 | eee | 890123 | online | **0** | **0** | **2** |

My idea would be to run a script daily and check if the counters are the same, adding incremental columns to a view_B, so that view_B would be:

**View_B** ( What I want )

| ID | Name | Code | Status | Counter_A | Counter_B | Counter_C | Counter_A_check | Counter_B_check | Counter_C_check |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | aaa | 971283 | online | 0 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 | **1** |
| 02 | bbb | 287301 | online | 0 | 2 | 2 | **1** | 0 | 0 |
| 03 | ccc | 718923 | online | 5 | 5 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 04 | ddd | 789021 | online | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 05 | eee | 890123 | online | 0 | 0 | 2 | **1** | **1** | **1** |

If the data is not the same, then I increase the value by one.
In this way I would know in addition to the discrepancy, also for how many days the values have been misaligned.
In the example, 1 = one-day misaligned.

it seems to work but I don't know how to implement it in SQL

Currently I have set up the two tables. The View_B and the script are missing.

Comment: You talk about the "days" the data has differed, however, there is no date column in your views, so how do you know what date the data in `VIEW_A` is and what date the data for `VIEW_B` is?

Comment: The idea is that view_A is cached once a day, while view_B takes the data in real-time.

Running the script at the setted time, if I have a difference then I increase the value of the counter_check by one (+1). The next day this increment can go to zero and it means that the data is aligned, or it can increase again, going to two (another +1). This would mean that the data has not been aligned for two consecutive days. And so for the third day:

another "plus one" would indicate to me that they have not been aligned for three days. If I get zero instead, the data is aligned.

Comment: `VIEW`s aren't "cached" they are pseudo tables defined by a `SELECT`. If you want store data, you need to put that in a table, not a view.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry for the inaccuracy

Comment: So are these actually tables, *not* views?

Comment: Yeah, tables! I think that thinking about the project as Table_A, Table_B and the View_B containing the "check columns" is not incorrect, is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a view in SQL Server in this way.
Views can only "store" (not actually store) data derived from other tables.
You are asking your view `View_B` to store historical information that is not available in any table.

What you could do instead is to is to create a view `AB_Diff` that shows you in which records and in which columns you have differences, like this

```
CREATE VIEW AB_Diff (IDa, Counter_A_check,  Counter_B_check, Counter_C_check)
AS
SELECT  a.ID, 
        CASE WHEN a.Counter_A <>b.Counter_A THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, 
        CASE WHEN a.Counter_B <>b.Counter_B THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
        CASE WHEN a.Counter_C <>b.Counter_C THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
    FROM Table_A AS a
    INNER JOIN Table_B b ON b.ID = a.ID;
GO
```

Using your data this query `SELECT * FROM AB_Diff` would return:

| IDa | Counter_A_check | Counter_B_check | Counter_C_check |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | **1** | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | **1** | **1** | **1** |

You could now use this view to create a new table `AB_Hist_Diff` where you could store the sum of the day-by-day instances of the differences, using a stored procedure that you run daily. If you go that way, I recommend also creating a stored procedure to reset these historical data when useful.

If you still want to have your view `View_B`, you can create it using `Table_B` and `AB_Hist_Diff` as I created `AB_Diff` using `Table_A` and `Table_B`.

Makes sense?